# JBoss 7 is stuck on "starting"

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, startup

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3 on Mac 10.9.5.  JAVA_HOME is set to

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

However, when I startup JBoss, it never gets past “starting”.  Below is the log.  I’m happy to upgrade JBoss if that’s what it takes, I but don’t see any later versions on their download site — http://jbossas.jboss.org/downloads/ .

Anyway, below is the log:

```
JAVA_OPTS set to -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=1 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled  -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Djboss.vfs.cache=org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.IterableTimedVFSCache -Djboss.vfs.cache.TimedPolicyCaching.lifetime=86400 -Djavax.net.debug=true -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false

=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss-as-7.1.3.Final

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=1 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled  -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Djboss.vfs.cache=org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.IterableTimedVFSCache -Djboss.vfs.cache.TimedPolicyCaching.lifetime=86400 -Djavax.net.debug=true -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
10:49:36,554 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.3.GA
10:49:39,511 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
10:49:39,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.3.Final "Arges" starting
```

Comment: are you 100% sure that jvm used is 1.6? looking at the log you are using JDK 8, as that is first jvm reports VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0 AS7 doesn't boot on jdk8

Comment: YOu are right.  For some reason JBoss is ignoring my $JAVA_HOME environment varaible.  Unless I set that directly in the $JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.conf file, JDK 1.6 isn't getting picked up.

Comment: I had this when I used Java 8. Problem was solved by using Java 7.